# I want to set permissions on dependencies that perticular dependency is not downloaded by maven

Tags: maven, nexus

for abc user

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>application</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
   </repository>
 </distributionManagement>
```

For cfg user:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.efg</groupId>
  <artifactId>application</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <name>Releases</name>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
   </repository>
 </distributionManagement>
```

I deployed both these jars in my nexus,Now my question is abc user cann't download efg artifact, and efg user cann't download abc artifact. Is there any way for this, please help me in this.

Comment: Simply no way for that. The question is why do you need that? May be you need to use different repositories for such purpose but I'm not sure if you are going the right path....May be you can explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

With Nexus Repository 2.x you can use [repository targets](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/repository-targets.html) and associated security configuration called [repository target privileges](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/security-privileges.html) to achieve that.

Step by step:

- Configure repository target with the right regexp for the path desired (groupId based)
- Create repository target privilege with create, read, update and delete
- Create role
- Add desired repository target privilege to role
- Assign role to user

In addition you will probably have to disable anonymous read access since this is the default setting.

It works in OSS as well as Pro. You need to ensure that anonymous read is disabled and you then set up access for whatever should be allowed. It can be pretty complex to set up depending on what you need. Also keep in mind that the user interface will still show all artifact when browsing and such.. just e.g. download (=read) will not work as expected.

If you still cant make it work, reach out to us via the [mailing list or live chat.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/lists-live-chat-and-other-resources/)

Comment: can i set the permissions for the nexus users to download set of group id artifacts from nexus UI, if yes,can you explain in detail please.

Comment: Expanded the answer. The rest should be clear if you read the docs and follow through with it

Comment: Thanks, i read the whole document and its not working in my nexus oss, is it works only in nexus pro edition? because i tried with so many patterns but didn't worked.

Comment: Ammended answer some more